# Google Maps Places API: Identifying multi-location stores/franchises versus independent companies

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-nearby

Surely there must be a way to identify multiple Place results representing multiple locations for the same organization versus result records for one-off stores. However, it's not clear how to do this.

Example search results for McDonald's:

https://jsonblob.com/57d63d65e4b0dc55a4f47681

Example details result for one of them:

https://jsonblob.com/57d63fd5e4b0dc55a4f47693

If you compare the results, the only thing they have in common are the name and the website: The "id", "place_id", and "reference" values all differ.

Any insights? I realize that there's no authoritative way for this to be correct unless the parent organizations post a list of locations to Google, but, obviously, Google still groups them at some level (because the info for any one location may sometimes describe headquarters or home-office information).

Comment: Wouldn't textsearch be enough for multi-location/franchise store searches? Or are you asking something more specific? The data on Places are different from Maps, which can be added using the [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) API.

Comment: I don't think that the owner of the place can be exposed. There is a [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/) where owners can manage their places, but I'm not aware of something else.

Comment: @adjuremods Sometimes there is a need to store information for a place that has more than one address, not N times for N addresses.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to identify if some places belong to specific chains or franchises.

This is not possible in Places API, other than by detecting *likely* relation to chains based on the `"name"` and `"website"` fields. But if you'd like to reliable detect this kind of relation, consider [filing a feature request for Places API](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request) (I couldn't find one).